# Dynamic widgets on GridLayout with ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy

Similar posts couldn't actually help me. Hence posting my own scenario. I have a grid layout area within other layouts. Now the number of rows of this grid is dynamic. It's a data table. Every time when user presses the Add button a new row need to be appended. And when the list grows to be more that the layout size the scroll bar should appear.

I've replicated the core part in below code. I've tried to work with Recycle view but couldn't succeed. Hence now the algorithm which I'm trying to work out is -

- when add button is pressed, calls a python function which collects the data for next 4 cells and adds 4 more buttons to the grid layout.
- when the Grid rows reaches above an 'x' value scroll bars appears.

## mydatatable.py

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'gl'
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class DataTable(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyTableApp(App):
    
    rowNumber = NumericProperty(2)
    
    def build(self):
        return DataTable()
       
    def add_a_row(self):
        self.rowNumber += 1    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyTableApp().run()
```

## mytable.kv

```
<DataTable>:
    orientation : 'vertical'
    
    Button:
        text : ""
    #---------------------------------- 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'horizontal'
        
        Button:
            text : ""
        #---------------------------------- 
        BoxLayout:
            orientation : 'vertical'
    
            GridLayout:
                cols : 4
                size_hint: 1.0, app.rowNumber*0.15
                
                Button:
                    text: "name"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                Button:
                    text: "type"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                Button:
                    text: "content"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                Button:
                    text: "xyz"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                    
                Button:
                    text: "name"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                Button:
                    text: "type"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                Button:
                    text: "content"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber 
                Button:
                    text: "xyz"
                    size_hint: 1, app.rowNumber     
        
            Label:
                size_hint: 1.0, (1.0 - (app.rowNumber-1)*0.15)
        #----------------------------------         
        Button:
            text : ""
    #---------------------------------- 
    Button: 
        text: "Add"
        on_release:
            app.add_a_row()
```

Or if there is a better way to achieve what I am looking for, please do advice. Thank you for your supports in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Kivy ScrollView & GridLayout

The following solution uses [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html) and [GridLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) to solve the problem.

- Replace the `BoxLayout` with `ScrollView` to support scrolling
- Add `id: container` to instantiated object, `GirdLayout:`
- Make sure the `GridLayout`'s height is such that there is something to scroll
- Set a default height for each row
- Add a class for a row

### Snippets - kv file

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"

    Button:
        text: "name"
    Button:
        text: "type"
    Button:
        text: "content"
    Button:
        text: "xyz"

...

<DataTable>:

        ScrollView:

            GridLayout:
                id: container
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_force_default: True
                row_default_height: dp(26)
```

### Snippets - Py file

```
class Row(BoxLayout):
    pass

...

class TestApp(App):

    ...

    def add_a_row(self):
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(Row())
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Now this taught me a good new lesson. Thank you ikolim for your prompt responses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still struggling to set this out. I can't find anything like adding a new widget which already hasn't declared in the initial design file. I'm having a feeling like, kivy doesnt have such an option.

Only practical solution would be to make the RecycleView work.